# Error while uploading huge base64 file to S3 Bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a huge video file to the s3 bucket. 
I am getting the data from the client-side in base64 format which I am sending to the S3client to upload to my bucket as shown below:-

```
public class UploadFileService {
    private static final String BUCKET_NAME = "data";
    private static final Regions REGION = Regions.US_EAST_2;

    LoggerUtils loggerUtils = new LoggerUtils ();

    public String uploadFile(String fileData, String fileName, String contentType, String extension){
        try {
            loggerUtils.log ("File Data" ,  fileData);
            byte[] bI = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64 ((fileData.substring (fileData.indexOf (",") + 1)).getBytes ());
            InputStream fis = new ByteArrayInputStream (bI);
            AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client ();
            Region usWest02 = Region.getRegion (REGION);
            s3.setRegion (usWest02);
            ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata ();
            metadata.setContentLength (bI.length);
             metadata.setContentType ("video/mp4");
            //metadata.setContentType (contentType + "/" + extension.substring (1));
            metadata.setCacheControl ("public, max-age=0");
            s3.putObject (BUCKET_NAME, fileName, fis, metadata);
            s3.setObjectAcl (BUCKET_NAME, fileName, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
            URL s3Url = s3.getUrl(BUCKET_NAME, fileName);
            return  s3Url.toExternalForm();
        }
        catch (Exception exception){
            loggerUtils.log (exception.toString ());
            throw exception;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "abc1.mp4";
        String fileData = "hkbk";
        new UploadFileService ().uploadFile (fileData, fileName, null, null);
    }
}
```

But if the fileData is usage (base64 of a 2MB video) then I am getting the below error:-

```
Error:(46, 27) java: constant string too long
```

Comment: Which is line 46? The line that reads `byte[] bI = ...`?

Comment: You might consider writing the file to disk first (which makes it easy to test that the file was correctly constructed), and then uploading the file from disk to Amazon S3 (rather than passing it from memory).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - It is not a gd approach though to save in file first and then read from the file.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - the S3 code is running on the server. How can i pass the file from the client to the server .

Comment: @Sunny I am simply suggesting that you change the above code by writing the data to a local file, then using `putObject()` by passing a reference to the **file** rather than providing an InputStream. The code would run exactly where it is already running.